# Using Tensor Flow CNN for prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to tensorflow. I have manged to train and validate a CNN, saved the session through the Saver object into a CPKT file and loaded it back. Now I'd like to use the trained model in order to check how it performs against a photo I took myself. I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

- Use a `tf.train.Saver()` object

  ```
  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  with tf.Session() as sess:
      saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Great to hear! All you need to do is to [load the checkpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables), and evaluate the network against it. That is typically done using the same script as the training script, but only evaluating the loss function with a batch size of `1`.

Comment: I understand I have to load the session and run it providing my input through the feed dictionary. I was however wondering if running the session keeps training the model. I am just interested in using it as it is.

Comment: You don't have to save the session. You can use a new session.